# GridSearchCV saving model while running error with Keras extenstion

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to automatize finding hyperparameters for model, but when I'm using GridSearchCV I'm getting error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dnom.png)

line110: grid_result.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=0) that's where getting error.

Which means that i should add .keras extension, but how i even should do that inside of class? Cause, I looked at it inside and there's nowhere filepath of similar
Any help?

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
import librosa
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import dill as pickle
import csv
import joblib
# Preprocessing
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
# Keras
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import keras

def generate_dataset():
    # Generating a dataset
    header = 'filename chroma_stft rmse spectral_centroid spectral_bandwidth rolloff zero_crossing_rate'
    for i in range(1, 21):
        header += f' mfcc{i}'
    header += ' label'
    header = header.split()

    file = open('data.csv', 'w', newline='')
    with file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(header)

    # Modify the label here
    types = ['ukrainian', 'other']

    for t in types:
        for filename in os.listdir(f'./music/{t}/'):
            songname = f'./music/{t}/{filename}'
            y, sr = librosa.load(songname, mono=True)
            chroma_stft = librosa.feature.chroma_stft(y=y, sr=sr)
            rmse=librosa.feature.rms(y=y)[0]
            spec_cent = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=y, sr=sr)
            spec_bw = librosa.feature.spectral_bandwidth(y=y, sr=sr)
            rolloff = librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(y=y, sr=sr)
            zcr = librosa.feature.zero_crossing_rate(y)
            mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr)
            to_append = f'{filename} {np.mean(chroma_stft)} {np.mean(rmse)} {np.mean(spec_cent)} {np.mean(spec_bw)} {np.mean(rolloff)} {np.mean(zcr)}'    
            for e in mfcc:
                to_append += f' {np.mean(e)}'
            # Append the label to each row
            to_append += f' {t}'
            file = open('data.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF-8')
            with file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow(to_append.split())
    return data
def open_dataset():
     # Reading dataset from CSV
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='latin-1', on_bad_lines='skip')

    # Dropping unnecessary columns
    data = data.drop(['filename'], axis=1)
    return data
 
def create_model(optimizer='adam', activation='relu'):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    # Adjust the output units based on the number of unique labels
    model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    return model

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='latin-1', on_bad_lines='skip')

    # Dropping unnecessary columns
data = data.drop(['filename'], axis=1)
    # Encode labels
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(data['label'])
# Normalizing
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(data.iloc[:, :-1], dtype=float))
# Splitting of dataset into train and test dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
# Creating a model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model())

param_grid = {
    'epochs':[10, 50, 100],
    'batch_size': [32, 64, 128],
    'activation': ['relu', 'softmax', 'sigmoid'], 
    'optimizer': ['adam', 'adamw', 'rmsprop']
}
    
grid_result = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
    
grid_result.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
    
best_model = grid_result.best_estimator_
best_model.model.save('best_model.h5')  
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

Comment: Please [do not use linked images for the error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15019223).